# NameError: uninitialized constant User(when I rails g forem:install)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a gem of [forum](https://github.com/rubysherpas/forem),and install it.but error,here is some log:

```
  Creating default forum and topic
    /Users/zhangxiaodong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
```

and I don't know how to do it?(I am new rails.)

Comment: Please expand this question to include the steps you've already tried. The error says no "User".  The documentation states you need a User system like Devise installed. Did you do that?

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't devise install.now I do it, it's go well. I love you. I love stackoverflow.